# Must Wallace's replicants obey?

Tags: plot-explanation, blade-runner-2049

(Actually, I already know the answer to question in the title, but I did not want the title to include any spoilers.)

Wallace is allowed to create replicants on the premise that his new breed of replicants always obey.

How, then, does K stop obeying and start pursuing his own agenda? And how do the replicant rebels expect to assemble a replicant army?

Answer (score 5):

The answer to your first question is a bit complicated, so I'll try my best to explain. Replicants are *not* robots in the sense that they are strictly programmable by 0s and 1s. They are more or less genetically enhanced humans. When they say Nexus 9s are "built to obey and never rebel", that's not entirely accurate. Nexus 9s operate on the basis of a brainwashing mechanism, which is done using the "Baseline Test". After a traumatic experience, Nexus 9s are required to take this test, in order to make sure they stay robot-like and obedient, and not start developing human emotions. This is a rather effective mean for brainwashing.

Now, when K realized that *he* was the child, he suddenly had the idea that he is not a Nexus 9, and that he had been brainwashed all along. This infuriating realization thrust him into the mood for rebellion. Besides, he had to lie anyways, because if the LAPD knew *he* was the child, they would kill him.

The answer to your second question is fairly simple. The Replicant Freedom Movement is lead by older models, not Nexus 9s. As such, they are all fugitives because they are not "built to obey", and are considered hazardous. Remember, replicants were banned following the Blackout, so only Nexus 9s are legal, since they were introduced by Wallace and can be trusted. Or can they? ;)

Comment: Regarding the replicant freedom movement: that makes sense; it wasn't clear to me that it was composed solely of older models.  However, how many older models are still around?  I imagine that to have the kind of uprising they seem to want that they would need numbers from the Nexus 9s as well.

Comment: less, brainwashing, more conditioning: but +1 either way.

Comment: K wasn't the child.

Comment: @his That's what he thought when he was disobeying. Sorry for not clarifying.